# Run only a background service when application start

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to start only to start a service when my application start. Here is my code:

My Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
 @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

     Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

   // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
   // stopped, so return sticky.
   return START_STICKY;
  }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class MyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
}
```

And my AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service
      android:name=".MyService"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:process=":my_process" >
    </service>

    <receiver 
        android:name=".MyServiceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

I want to start my service when the application start (is installed the first time) and  when the device boot.

P.S. If the code is right, maybe I have to setup a particular configuration for the eclipse "run" button? If try to create a new configuration I can't select nothing in "Launch action" because my application haven't an activity, and I have to select "Do nothing".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a main activity to call this service within `onCreate` if you want the service to start as soon as you start your application. In your main activity, include this code in your onCreate:

`startService(new Intent(Main_Activity.this,MyServiceReceiver.class));`

This is just to call your service when you start up your application.

Comment: but when the activity completes completes the service and when I get call activity rerun the service, the idea is that the service runs one you see when you start the app.