# How to keep an app running in the background in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an app where I have to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a location and save in a database. Second thing is that I want the user to get a notification when he reaches the same place again. i have no idea how to keep the app running in the background. can anyone give me an idea how to proceed?

Comment: services will help you  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Whenever you want to run your app in background you need to use Service which can be handle your app in background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use service to work:

Useful tutorial:

1. http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-services-and-intents-in-android-applications/28647
2. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has already been asked here:
[Run only a background service when application start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064132/run-only-a-background-service-when-application-start)

There is also a thread about this on Appcelerator:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/138478/background-service-on-android

Also, you can find a tutorial for Android Services here:
http://danielnadeau.blogspot.com/2013/10/android-services-tutorial-run-tasks-in.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 types of components an android app can consist of: Broadcast Receivers, Content Providers, Activities and Services. You need Services.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html#Components